# Check if a parameter is a Python module?

Tags: python, types

How can I (pythonically) check if a parameter is a Python module? There's no type like module or package.

```
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/os.pyc'>

>>> isinstance(os, module)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/pythonconsole/console.py", line 290, in __run
    r = eval(command, self.namespace, self.namespace)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'module' is not defined
```

I can do this:

```
>>> type(os)
<type 'module'>
```

But what do I compare it to? :(

I've made a simple module to quickly find methods in modules and get help texts for them. I supply a module var and a string to my method:

```
def gethelp(module, sstring):

    # here i need to check if module is a module.

    for func in listseek(dir(module), sstring):
        help(module.__dict__[func])
```

Of course, this will work even if module = 'abc': then dir('abc') will give me the list of methods for string object, but I don't need that.

Comment: You are aware of the help() method and pydoc and similar efforts, right?

Comment: pydoc is a bit different. I needed a simple way to find a method without knowing it's exact name. For example, something that has 'size' in os.path.

Comment: Can't you Duck Type a module? What do you need it for? Just try that and catch the exception if it fails.

Comment: Well, docs and help is a type of introspection, so in this case it seems alright.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
from types import ModuleType

isinstance(obj, ModuleType)
```

Comment: why this is accepted answer? package is also an instance of ModuleType

Comment: @Wang I don't believe there is any distinction between a "package" and a "module" in Python. They are all modules.

Comment: While they are the same type, there are distinctions. Namely, package instances do not have a `__module__` field, and, unlike a true *module*, the `__package__` field of a package instance does not represent the parent package but the given package.

Answer (score 43):

```
>>> import inspect, os
>>> inspect.ismodule(os)
True
```

Comment: If your testing the dictionary from `globals().values()` to find/remove modules for some reason `ismodule()` doesnt work had to use `isclass()`...

Comment: @nimig18: To find all modules in `globals()`:
    `[k for k in globals().keys() if ismodule(eval(k))]`

Answer (score 10):

This seems a bit hacky, but:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> type(os) is type(sys)
True
```

Comment: Hehe, in standard library, module `types`, found this: `ModuleType = type(sys)` :)

Answer (score 3):

A mix of [@Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547469/7515957) and [@Lennart Regebro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547475/7515957) answers:

```
>>> from types import ModuleType
>>> import os
>>> type(os) is ModuleType
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the module to a string and check if it starts with `'<module '`

```
import matplotlib
foobarbaz = "some string"
print(str(matplotlib).startswith("<module "))     #prints True
print(str(foobarbaz).startswith("<module "))      #prints False
```

Drawback being this could collide with a python string that starts with the text `'<module'`  You could try to classify it more strongly with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this without importing anything else is to make it a string and directly compare to the output:

```
import os

print(str(type(os)))  #Prints "<class 'module'>"

print(str(type(os))) == "<class 'module'>")  #Prints True
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways,you could not import any modules:

- `type(os) is type(__builtins__)`
- `str(type(os)).find('module')>-1`

Comment: In 3.7.1 `print(type(__builtins__))` is `<class 'dict'>` and not `<class 'module'>`